# Getting first tuple from a set

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have this set:

`optimal = {(0,1),(2,1),(1,1)}`

I want to get the very first tuple from the set.

The desired output is:
`(0,1)`

How can I do this?

Comment: list(optimal)[0]

Comment: That will not always return what you want. Sets are not ordered. Try printing it multiple times.

Comment: There's no such thing as the "first" tuple of a set. The set iterator will yield the values in some arbitrary order that you cannot necessarily predict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets don't have an inherent ordering on their elements (by default, at least).

So you need to do two things:

1. turn it into something that does have an ordering -- `as_list = list(optimal)`
2. sort that list -- `as_list.sort()`

Now the items are in *some* order, which by default is the natural ordering of the elements. For a list of tuples this means `as_list[0]` is now `(0,1)`

Check out the documentation for [sorting in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/sorting.html) to learn how to sort by other criteria.

**NB** answers which simply say convert to list and get element [0] ignore the fact that the set does not yield its elements to the list in a predictable order.

Comment: Sorting is probably overkill. "First" implies "least" according to some criteria, which `min` can probably handle. `min` can also be applied to an arbitrary iterable, including a `set`. (Also, `sorted` can also return a list given an arbitrary iterable.)

Comment: @chepner Only if we know that the natural ordering is adequate, moerover my point about how the list is actually constructed from the set still holds. We don't know why (0,1) is special to the OP.

Comment: That's why I said "according to some criteria"; you can specify a `key` argument to either `min` or `sorted` to map the tuples in an order-preserving way to values with the desired ordering.

Comment: @chepner we agree -- hence my direction to the docs for more on sorting, in which `key` is important.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* no first element of a `set()`.

If you want the first value of an array, there must've been a pattern, loop, or method that got you the set, or, you manually made the set of elements. 
In either cases, what you need is a `list`. 
If the set was used to get rid of duplicates, you can do the same with:

```
ls = [...]
lst = []
[lst.append(e) for e in ls if e not in lst]
```

Answer (score -2):

use optimal.pop() it returns the first value from the set.

Comment: pop() only removes an remove tuple from the set